# Need help omitting folders in find command

Tags: bash

I have this line in a script I'm writing

```
find / \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -v ELF | cut -d":" -f1 >> $OUTPUT
```

It does the work, BUT I always get these messages I want to omit

```
find: `/proc/29527/task/29527/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/29527/task/29527/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/29527/fd/5': No such file or directory
find: `/proc/29527/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
```

How can I omit the `/proc` directory?

Comment: find / -name proc -prune -o ....

Comment: find / ... \; 2> /dev/null | grep ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
find / -path /proc -prune -o \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f ...
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Add this to your command line
```

Comment: Don't see how the question called for omitting `/proc`?

Comment: BroSlow, maybe i was not clear on my question, my apologies,  what i wanted was to omit the /proc folder from the find so i could get rid of the errors

Comment: @ Sean Bright:  What if i want to do multiple folders and not just /proc?  should i just add the name right to it?

Comment: @user3635042 Redirecting `stderr` still makes more sense to me, but you can just add more paths like `find / \( -path /proc -o -path /somethingelse -o path somethingelse2 \) -prune -o \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f ...`

Answer (score 1):

What if you redirect `STDERR` to `/dev/null`. That way, you don't see the unwanted error/warning in your TTY (`STDOUT`) like

```
{ find / \( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f -exec file {} \; | grep -v ELF | cut -d":" -f1 >> $OUTPUT; } 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Still get the same output.

Comment: @Rahul I think you need to redirect stderr in the `-exec` as well, since it executes a subshell

Comment: @BroSlow, I don't think. But yes, I swapped the position redirect error .. redirect o/p.

Comment: @Rahul That makes no difference `>>` is only redirecting stdout anyway

Comment: @BroSlow, that's should work fine but have no way to test it. If you have tested then I will have to believe?

Comment: @Rahul Just try something like `find /proc -type f -exec file {} \; | grep something >> out 2>/dev/null`. You should see some `permission denied` errors or other `stderr`. You can either add redirection inside the exec like `-exec file {} 2>/dev/null` or group the entire thing like `{ find /proc -type f -exec file {} \; | grep something >> out; } 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @BroSlow, that makes sense but as said I have no way to test it currently. Please don't hesitate to edit my post if you feel that will make the answer more accurate. appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The following prunes the proc directory:

```
find / -name /proc -prune -o \
\( -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 \) -type f \
-exec file {} \; | grep -v ELF | cut -d":" -f1 >> $OUTPUT
```